# How to custom spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, customization

I want custom spinner in android like below description
- Place Holder Text (Spinner first item - selected item will be centered )
- Drop down list item will be left-aligned

[image]

I try to use custom layout adapter for Spinner but just only align for both spinner and drop down list.
I hope somebody can help me with it ! I'm newbie with Android , sorry about that!

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example that I've used in an app recently.

Create 2 files in your res/layout folder, one called spinner_list.xml and one called spinner_list_dropdown.xml.

spinner_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/text_view_text"/>
```

spinner_list_dropdown.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/text_view_text"
    android:background="@color/spinner_background"/>
```

Java code for using the custom spinner:

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(YourActivity.this, R.layout.spinner_list, strYourArray);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_list_dropdown);
        spinnerCustomList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope this all makes sense to you, if you need any help with it then please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you , do you have example for multi layout for spinner ?

Comment: @EddyLee did this help you?